# Selecting from DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS causes ora-1000

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Sometimes, when I execute (usually on the 3rd run):

```
 select * from DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS;
```

I receive ora-1000 : Maximum open cursors exceeded.
But i don't exceed the maximum cursors. Any suggestion how to get rid of this error will be useful.
My database is Oracle 11gR2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is "Bug 17897511  ORA-1000 from query on DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS after upgrade to 11.2.0.4 - superseded".  (A My Oracle Support account is required to view all details of the bug.)

There is a bug with the trigger on this view.  Turn off autoextend for all your datafiles and the cursor issue will go away.  Or download and apply the patch.